# How to send message from Apache Kafka server to another server?

Tags: apache-kafka

I install Apache Kafka on two virtual machine with the following ip address:
192.168.44.128 (A) and 192.168.44.129 (B)

From PC-A, I create topic on PC-B, it successes. I used this command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 192.168.44.129:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic abc
```

Then, I want to send message from PC-A to PC-B, it don't have any error, but I can't get message at B. Please help me.

I use this command, to send and get message:

```
 On PC-A
> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.44.129:9092 --topic abc
Hello
How are you??
 On PC-B
> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic abc --from-beginning
```

Comment: I assume you are running separate `zookeeper` and `kafka` servers on `PC-A` and `PC-B`. If you have access to both zookeeper and kafka of `PC-B` from `PC-A` then you can successfully create, produce, consume and delete topics from `PC-A`. So make sure you have access to produce message to `PC-B` from `PC-A`!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
On PC-A
> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.44.128:9092 --topic abc
Hello
How are you??
 On PC-B
> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 192.168.44.129:2181 --topic abc --from-beginning
```